# C# WCF Sessions with Asynchronous functions

Tags: wcf, session

What happens in the case of a wcf session that has created an asynchronous function (such as background automated emailing ) when the client closes session ie client.Close()/client.Abort()?

In otherwords if have some as below:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
void RegisterUser(string user);

[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
void SendEmails(T[] listofDetails);

[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
void UnRegisterUser();
```

and SendEmails creates a task or async function (the async call isn't done client side) that sends off all the emails in the background.
And the user Terminates the session before all the emails are finished sending? Does the session still stay open and wait or does it close and the emailing just keeps going until it finishes or what happens?
Thanks All 
Sorry if the question is a bit ambiguous :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have defined a request-response operation called SendEmails which returns void. This is not the same thing as an asynchronous operation.

I am assuming you are creating a new background thread within the operation method which then goes away and send the emails.

In this instance the operation will return void to the caller once the operation method has finished execution. If the client then terminates the channel the background thread will continue its work.

Comment: Yip yip :) I want the SendEmails to create the thread itself and return void :) So then the thread created by the session will continue to run even after the session is closed from the client side :)